# Libgdx what's the best practice to save item lists?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I'm making a game and there's in game store where you can buy items. For the items that are selected i can perfectly use Preferences and save variables. But now I need to check if the player owns the item so he can't buy it the second time . What would be the most efficient way for doing this ? Since if my store has 100 items I don't want to be stuck writing 100 booleans ...

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in this case would be to serialize the list of items to a file, either via XML or JSON.

- [JSON serializing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON)
- [XML serializing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-xml)

I'd advice you to use JSON, because the format probably results in smaller files and the libgdx JSON serialization framework is pretty powerful. In most cases you won't even need to write a `Serializer` yourself, because libgdx uses reflection to serialize it.